# Rewriting Views results with tokens on multi field

Tags: 7, views, tokens

I need to write a paragraph laced with field values from a result from a view.  For example, "Our camera case works with model ABC, 123, and XYZ", where ABC, 123, and XYZ are 3 out of multiple results values for that field.

Can I use tokens to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes using field_fieldnamename:delta

"Our camera case works with model [field_fieldnamename:0], [field_fieldnamename:1], and [field_fieldnamename:2]"

Comment: You answered my question, but I actually asked wrong. I was curious how to combine multiple results.